# Filter by multiple keys and values, Javascript

Tags: javascript, filter

I'm trying to make a filter. The number of filters will change dynamically, a number of keys can be different, and the number of values, too.

This is how data look like:

```
var data = [
{id: "123", color: "Red", model: "Tesla"}, 
{id: "124", color: "Black", model: "Honda"}, 
{id: "125", color: "Red", model: "Audi"}, 
{id: "126", color: "Blue", model: "Tesla"}]
```

Filter keys are color and model. But sometimes I will filter only by color or model and sometimes by both. I want to make a function that will cover both cases. Also, a user can choose many values (Tesla, Honda...).

Key can be only color, or only model, or both.
Values can look like: only "Red", "Red" and "Blue", or "Red" and "Tesla", or "Red", "Blue" and "Tesla"... Depends on what user choose.

I tried this:

```
var filtered = [];
data.forEach(item => {
   filterByKey.forEach(key => {
      values.forEach(value => {
         if (item[key] === value) {
             filtered.push(item);
          }
       });
    });
  });
```

Here is [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/snoopy_15/kb9ouddu/)

My loop works well when I have one filter key, but it doesn't work well when I have more than one key. Is it a good idea to pass keys and values as an array?

No jQuery please, only pure JavaScript.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `filter()` with `every()` and check if value of current object with current key exits in `values` array using `includes()`

```js
var data = [{"id":"123","color":"Red","model":"Tesla"},{"id":"124","color":"Black","model":"Honda"},{"id":"125","color":"Red","model":"Audi"},{"id":"126","color":"Blue","model":"Tesla"}]

var keys = ["color", 'model'];
var values = ["Tesla", "Audi", "Red"];

var result = data.filter(function(e) {
  return keys.every(function(a) {
    return values.includes(e[a])
  })
})

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!

Comment: Hey Nenad, function works great, but working with it I figured out one case we missed. That case is when same value repeats for values. Color and model have same value. It's a stupid example, but let's say a color is "Red" and model is "Red", too. Should I maybe pass key and values together as an object? What do you suggest? Thanks!

Comment: Hey, Nenad? Can you help me, please?

Comment: @snoopy25 I don't see the problem https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/2114/ it will return it.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) where the function to test each element of the array  is:

`` el => !!filterBy.toString().match(new RegExp(`(?=.*${el.color})(?=.*${el.model})`)) ``

It consist of a regular expression `` new RegExp(`(?=.*${el.color})(?=.*${el.model})`)) `` that match to strings `color` and `model` in another string `filterBy.toString()`

```js
var data = [{id: "123", color: "Red", model: "Tesla"}, {id: "124", color: "Black", model: "Honda"}, {id: "125", color: "Red", model: "Audi"}, {id: "126", color: "Blue", model: "Tesla"}],
    filterBy = ['Tesla', 'Audi', 'Red', 'Black'],
    result = data.filter(el => !!filterBy.toString().match(new RegExp(`(?=.*${el.color})(?=.*${el.model})`)));

console.log(result);
```

And also, you can combine [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [Array.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

```js
var data = [{id: "123", color: "Red", model: "Tesla"}, {id: "124", color: "Black", model: "Honda"}, {id: "125", color: "Red", model: "Audi"}, {id: "126", color: "Blue", model: "Tesla"}],
    filterBy = ['Tesla', 'Audi', 'Red', 'Black'],
    result = data.filter(el => filterBy.includes(el.model) && filterBy.includes(el.color));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 6):

You could use a combined approach with a seach object which keeps the conditions, like

> ```
> { 
>     model: 'Tesla',                                    // a single value
>     color: ['red', 'blue'],                            // a some value
>     price: {                                           // a range/interval
>         min: 2000, 
>         max: 3000
>     },
>     transmission: v => v.toLowerCase() === 'automatic' // a function
> }
> ```

```js
var useConditions = search => a => Object.keys(search).every(k => 
        a[k] === search[k] ||
        Array.isArray(search[k]) && search[k].includes(a[k]) ||
        typeof search[k] === 'object' && +search[k].min <= a[k] &&  a[k] <= +search[k].max ||
        typeof search[k] === 'function' && search[k](a[k])
    ),
    data = [{ id: "123", color: "Red", model: "Tesla" }, { id: "124", color: "Black", model: "Honda" }, { id: "125", color: "Red", model: "Audi" }, { id: "126", color: "Blue", model: "Tesla" }],
    filters = { color: ['Red', 'Blue'], model: 'Tesla' };

console.log(data.filter(useConditions(filters)));
```

Comment: this should be the accepted answer, simple and amazing ! thanks

Answer (score 1):

For a case like this here's what I just do:

```
function _filter(data, query) { // query = "Red" or "Tesla"
    return data.filter(el => {
        return el.model.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) !== -1 ||
        el.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
    });
}
```

Now this function searches data on the model key and name key.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want to achieve?

```js
var data = [
  {id: "123", color: "Red", model: "Tesla"}, 
  {id: "124", color: "Black", model: "Honda"}, 
  {id: "125", color: "Red", model: "Audi"}, 
  {id: "126", color: "Blue", model: "Tesla"}
];

var allowedColors = ["Red", "Blue"];
var allowedModels = ["Tesla", "Audi"];

function filter (cars, colors, models) {
  return cars.filter(function (car) {
    return colors.indexOf(car.color) !== -1 && // check if the car's color is allowed
      models.indexOf(car.model) !== -1;        // check if the car's model is allowed
  });
}

var filtered = filter(data, allowedColors, allowedModels);
console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: I think he might want to be able to set models or colors to null, with the meaning "all".

Comment: This works well only for this case, but if I want to group filter only colors or only models this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Filtering is native in JS, try this:

```
data.filter(item => item.color==='Red');
// or in the old fashion 
data.filter(function(item){ return item.color==='Red';} );
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, I have a different scenario.

I have an object

```
d={r1: {name: "r1", validation: true}, r2: {name: "r2", validation: true}};
```

and another array

```
a = ["r1"];
```

Here, the result I want is

```
d={r1: {name: "r1", validation: true}}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Using `filter()` to filter data, combined with `some()` to check if multiple `keys` match **at least one** of the strings from the `values` using `includes()`

```
// array --------------------

const data = [
  { id: '123', color: 'Red', model: 'Tesla' },
  { id: '124', color: 'Black', model: 'Honda' },
  { id: '125', color: 'Red', model: 'Audi' },
  { id: '126', color: 'Blue', model: 'Tesla' },
];



// filter exact match --------------------

const keysExact = ['color', 'model'];
const valuesExact = ['Tesla', 'Audi', 'Red'];

const resultExact = data.filter((item) =>
  keysExact.every((a) => valuesExact.includes(item[a]))
);

console.log(resultExact);
// result:
// [
//   { id: '123', color: 'Red', model: 'Tesla' },
//   { id: '125', color: 'Red', model: 'Audi' },
// ];
```

---

[image]

Using `filter()` to filter data, combined with `some()` to check if multiple `keys` contain **at least one** of the strings from the `values` using `includes()`.

```js
// array --------------------

const data = [
  { id: '123', color: 'Red', model: 'Tesla' },
  { id: '124', color: 'Black', model: 'Honda' },
  { id: '125', color: 'Red', model: 'Audi' },
  { id: '126', color: 'Blue', model: 'Tesla' },
];



// filter data by keys containing values string (at least one of the string in values) --------------------

const keysSome = ['color', 'model'];
const valuesSome = ['Tes', 're'];

const resultSome = data.filter((item) =>
  keysSome.some((key) =>
    valuesSome.some((val) => item[key].toLowerCase().includes(val.toLowerCase()))
  )
);

console.log(resultSome);
// result:
// [
//   { id: '123', color: 'Red', model: 'Tesla' },
//   { id: '125', color: 'Red', model: 'Audi' },
//   { id: '126', color: 'Blue', model: 'Tesla' },
// ];
```

---

[image]

Using `filter()` to filter data, combined with `every()` to check if multiple `keys` contain **all** strings from the `values` using `includes()`.

```js
// array --------------------

const data = [
  { id: '123', color: 'Red', model: 'Tesla' },
  { id: '124', color: 'Black', model: 'Honda' },
  { id: '125', color: 'Red', model: 'Audi' },
  { id: '126', color: 'Blue', model: 'Tesla' },
];



// filter data by keys containing values string (matches all strings from values) --------------------

const keysEvery = ['color', 'model'];
const valuesEvery = ['Tes', 're'];

const resultEvery = data.filter((item) =>
  keysEvery.every((key) =>
    valuesEvery.some((val) => item[key].toLowerCase().includes(val.toLowerCase()))
  )
);

console.log(resultEvery);
// result:
// [
//   { id: '123', color: 'Red', model: 'Tesla' }
// ]
```

Comment: Did you use a specific website to get these visual search results ?

Comment: I actually design it in Figma since I'm a designer as well.